# Building a .deb package in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ubuntu

I have Visual Studio 2017 running on Windows pc and i am working on a c++ project. I need a .deb package so that my finished c++ project on Ubuntu runs. How can i do this? I searched on Internet and on Stack overflow but I didn't found anything. Thanks for the help!

Comment: To clarify: You want Visual Studio to produce a .deb file  that you can easily install on a Debian-based Linux distribution, yes?

Comment: Yeah, it's what I need.

Comment: Are you having problem with building .deb package or with making working script / makefile (or whatever build system you are using to build that package) work from VS?

Comment: No, I do not know how to build a .deb package. I do not have any errors.

Comment: Can't help you with this one. I do close to zero Linux development on Windows and even then the final builds are on Linux machines.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with c++, visual-studio or programming. [How to build a Debian package](https://wiki.debian.org/HowToPackageForDebian). I'm not sure if it is possible from Windows as you use debuild for this

Comment: Also you can't build a binary on Windows and run it on Linux. You have to build on Linux

Comment: I've been assuming the Asker is using a cross compiler. Perhaps a bad assumption, no?